# Invalid redeclaration of 'mapView(_:viewFor:)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I'm trying to create an app with custom annotations on the map, and I've been following a tutorial on how to do it. However when I put this code in, its giving me the error

Invalid redeclaration of 'mapView(_:viewFor:)'

Here's the tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_aw72i8P_U

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let _annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else {return }
        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        }
        else
        {
           view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally happens when you already implemented that method elsewhere.

Check your ViewController to make sure you don't have `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {}` implemented outside of that extension.